# Send file via whatsapp from Python

Tags: python, selenium, whatsapp

I was trying to send one file using Python Selenium web driver. But I am not able to locate the send button using python. I can see below HTML using inspect:

Also my web whatsapp screen is not progressing after file send screen [Whatsapp web screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZadxB.png)

I used below code:

```
fileToSend = file
#Get whatsapp contact
WebDriverWait(driver, wait).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.jN-F5')))
search = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.jN-F5')
search.send_keys(user + Keys.ENTER)
# click to add
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('span[data-icon="clip"]').click()
# add file to send by file path
attach=driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[type="file"]')
attach.send_keys(fileToSend) 
send=self.driver.find_element_by_class_name('yavlE')
```

Below is html source code :

```html
 <div role="button" class="_3hV1n yavlE">
        <span data-icon="send-light" class="">
            <svg id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 28 24" width="28" height="24">
                <path fill="#FFF" d="M5.101 21.757L27.8 12.028 5.101 2.3l.011 7.912 13.623 1.816-13.623 1.817-.011 7.912z"></path>
            </svg>
        </span>
    </div>
```

Please help.

Thanks,
Samir

Comment: What error are you getting? Can you share the error log?

Comment: File "C:\Users\ssingham\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"class name","selector":"yavlE"}
  (Session info: chrome=72.0.3626.81)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.45.615291 (ec3682e3c9061c10f26ea9e5cdcf3c53f3f74387),platform=Windows NT 10.0.15063 x86_64)

Comment: Try my answer and let me know the status, I have changed the locator

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong class name in the below step :

```
self.driver.find_element_by_class_name('yavlE')
```

Replace the above line with the below locator and try again :

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'yavlE')]");
```

Still you are getting NoSuchElementException then try to give some delay like below :

```
from time import sleep
sleep(3)
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'yavlE')]");
```

I hope it works...

Comment: Hi Ali, Thanks for your suggestion but it does not fix the issue. I am getting same error.

Comment: Give some delay before that step like `sleep(3)` - Import it `from time import sleep`

Comment: Thanks Ali, It worked now. (Just for my understanding) why simple delay was causing unnecessary errors.

Comment: Welcome...The script is trying to locate the element before the page gets loaded and so you are getting the NoSuchElementException. Please accept my answer if it works and give up vote. Thank you

Comment: Is your script is working for `self.driver.find_element_by_class_name('yavlE')` also or only for `self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'yavlE')]");`?

Comment: yes Ali, It worked for self.driver.find_element_by_class_name('yavlE') also. Only issue was with delay and after giving the delay it works.